# If a specific item is in array, set that item as last

Tags: php, arrays, woocommerce

I'm displaying related products based on the last item that was added to the cart in Woocommerce. I can get the last product ID easily and it works, but only when this product isn't already in the cart. When it is in the cart and added again, the last item will always be the last unique added item, which will return the wrong products for the last (again) added product.

What I think I need to do is check if this last item is already in the array, when it is in the array, remove the first instance and insert it as last. How can I do that? My code:

```
$cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();
$cart_is_empty = WC()->cart->is_empty();
$product_id = end($cart)['data']->post->ID;
$items_count = 3;

$exclude_ids = array();
$ids = array();

if(! $cart_is_empty ) {
 foreach ($cart as $cart_item) {
    $exclude_ids[] = $cart_item['product_id'];
    $ids[] = $cart_item['product_id'];              
}

$last_item = array_search($product_id, $ids);
    if($last_item !== 'false') {
    unset($ids[$last_item]);
    array_push($ids, $last_item);
}

$product_id = end($ids);

$related_products = WC()->get_related_products($product_id,$items_count,$excluded_ids);
```

Comment: The idea is working, but you can not use `array_search()` as you did. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search

Comment: Ah you're right, there was a bracket, I modified it thanks

Comment: We don't have any sample data as part of a [mcve]. Why do you access the last product from `$cart` with `end($cart)['data']->post->ID`, then later pull all ids from the cart array with `$cart_item['product_id']`. I have a suspicion that this whole script could be refined/reduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_search()` returns the found `key` or `false`, not the value itself. So you need to save the `value` before removing it, to add it later.

When you use type safe comparision (tripple equals) then you need to remove the quotes from `false`, otherwise it would compare to a string value "false".

Also do not use `array_push()` if you don't need to push multiple items. `$ids[] = $last_item;` is better and more performant, because no function needs to be called.

```
$last_item_key = array_search($product_id, $ids);
if ($last_item_key !== false) {
    $last_item = $ids[$last_item_key];
    unset($ids[$last_item_key]);
    $ids[] = $last_item;
}
```